# Working with dynamic collections on NestJs

Tags: typescript, mongoose, nestjs, mongoose-schema

I'm working in an app that the user enters with one of the various collection names available on my MongoDb, and my backend process it and do the search on the documents present on it. When i create a schema model on NestJs its looks like this:

```
import { Prop, Schema, SchemaFactory } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { HydratedDocument } from 'mongoose';

export type LogDocument = HydratedDocument<Log>;

@Schema({ collection: '41L0001859239Y' })
export class Log {
  @Prop()
  level: string;

  @Prop()
  message: string;
}

export const LogSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Log);
```

and the collection name there will be the one that the code will search when i do a log.find() for example, but i want it to be dynamiclly, like i said i will receive the collection name on the frontend and the backend will search on the especified.

I tried to turn my schema on a function:

```
export function DynamicSchema(collectionName) {
  @Schema({ collection: collectionName })
  class Log {
    @Prop()
    level: string;

    @Prop()
    message: string;
  }
  const DynamicSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Log);
  return mongoose.model('Log', DynamicSchema);
}
```

On the service layer i did this:

```
 console.log(this.logModel);
 const DynamicModel = DynamicSchema(gatewayId);
 console.log(DynamicModel);
 const query = await DynamicModel.find(options).limit(2);
 console.log(query);
 const totalDocuments = await DynamicModel.count(options).exec();
```

But i'm receiving this error:
[Nest] 8132  - 21/08/2023, 09:17:34   ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] Operation `41L0001859239Y.find()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
MongooseError: Operation `41L0001859239Y.find()` buffering timed out after 10000ms

Comment: I don't think collections are supposed to be dynamic. This is also evident from the fact that the document schema is the same between collections. Unless you are working on a truly exotic feature never before seen in the industry (which you probably don't, let's be honest), the choice of architecture is likely the issue. I'd suggest defining `Log` statically.

Comment: Its because for every gateway they have a unique id, and the log collection that they generate will be created using the id and i cant control this id and for any gateway working i will have a unique one, so doing it static would be a bad idea i think, so the collection need to be dynamic because the user is the one who will tell wich gateway he wanna see the logs. but i've already encoutered a solution for the problem, NestJs wasnt considering the schema on the connection, so doing the InjectConnection resolved it. now i can consult any collection that i have in the database.